# static hostname but dhcp for nameservers on centos7

Tags: centos, dhcp

I need the nameserver **from dhcp**, but I don't want the hostname or domain name. I need the nameserver, so setting /etc/resolve.conf doesn't work. Only way I've managed to get the system to use the hostname I give it is to create /etc/hostname. However, then my /etc/resolve.conf gets rewritten...

Running Centos 7. My /etc/resolv.conf looks like this after boot:

```
; generated by /usr/sbin/dhclient-script
search ec2.internal
nameserver 10.254.192.2
```

If I set a new hostname by `echo myhost.example.com > /etc/hostname` then NetworkManager boastfully rewrites /etc/resolve.conf as follows:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search ec2.internal

# No nameservers found; try putting DNS servers into your
# ifcfg files in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts like so:
#
# DNS1=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
# DNS2=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
# DOMAIN=lab.foo.com bar.foo.com
```

I need the nameserver from dhcp, but I don't want the hostname or domain name. I'm guessing there's a better way than my hack.

Comment: I had this same issue with Fedora Core 11 and came up with a hideous solution: use chattr to make /etc/resolv.conf immutable.

Comment: That's not a solution, because then dhclient can't tell me what my nameserver is.

Comment: how often does the name server change?  If you are configured for a static IP then you should be told what name server to configure on your end.  If you are getting the same IP via dhcp based on a static entry for your MAC address, then that same entry can be configured to send whatever search domain you want (or none), etc.